# notifications in flutter iOS not being received

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

The notification is receieved and displays onMessage"{the notification}" when i test in the simulator.
However, when I test on a physical device, the onmessage doesn't appear and the notification also does not work/appear.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
The problem is on IOS

Comment: @KabirouAgouda onMessage only appears on simulator and doesn't appear on physical device